# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled in MAC

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, mamp

I am trying to run PHP with MongoDB.

Currently I am successful at installing MongoDB but when I run a PHP script with MongoDB connection in my Localhost I get the error as follows.

```
The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled
```

I also installed PECL extension and I received the result below.

The MongoDB PECL installation gives me following output.

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.6.11
Extension mongo enabled in php.ini
```

I also added

```
extension="mongo.so"
```

in the php.ini file for the default PHP version I am using. I also restarted my server several times + restarted my computer ~4 times since yesterday to see if it fixed.

I have possibly refereed at-least 20 links from Google to fix this issue but it has not worked yet.

What could be the reason I am getting this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the full path to `php.ini`, restart apache and give a try

> extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so"